# Breaking apart a string and making the parts on array

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexof

I have the string Q and i want to separate it into multiple parts. For example i would like to have the (ADD equal 1 and (EXP 1 4) equal 2 and so on splitting up after each parentheses but still maintains the form of the string.

```
String q =(("(ADD(EXP 1 4)(SQR 1)(DIV 34 77)(MULT 12 5 3 7)(Sub 1 2"));
```

I've tried doing it like this but haven't had any success.

```
        s[0]=q.indexOf("(");
        s[1]=q.indexOf(")");
```

Comment: `indexOf` returns an integer, so the code you have so far creates an array of integers.

Comment: Sorry just Java, and i want them to be a set of smaller strings possibly in an array?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-.  Actually, that might help, but it's not really clear what you need.  Do you want each result string to start with `(`?  Or do you want something more complicated?

Comment: Use the String.split(<delimiters>);    This will allow you to have one or multiple delimiters. Then just go through and assign the correct sub-strings to your array.

Comment: If i split the string and then try to print out the string, will it print out fully? Or will it be fully split from the original?

Comment: `Strings` in Java are _immutable_.  That means the library doesn't provide any methods to alter the original string.  Everything you do will create a new string (or for `split`, an array of strings) but leave the original string alone.  Keep that in mind if you ever use `s.replace(...)` or something, because a lot of people incorrectly think they're changing `s` when they do this.

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
String q ="(ADD(EXP 1 4)(SQR 1)(DIV 34 77)(MULT 12 5 3 7)(Sub 1 2";
String[] result = q.split("(?=\\()");
```

produces the following strings in the result array:

```
"(ADD"
"(EXP 1 4)"
"(SQR 1)"
"(DIV 34 77)"
"(MULT 12 5 3 7)"
"(Sub 1 2"
```

but I'm not totally sure that's what you want (if it isn't, you'll need to clarify for us).

The argument to `split` is a regular expression.  It's common to use it with something like `"/"`, which will split an input string by slash characters.  But doing that doesn't leave the slash characters in the result.  To `split` on a string but leave the delimiters in the results, you need lookahead.  The regular expression above does that.  `(?=<something>)` looks ahead for some pattern but doesn't "consume" it; here the pattern is `\\(` which means a single `(` character, but it needs to be preceded by a backslash because `(` normally has special meanings in a regular expression.

Comment: When I print out  result it prints out    [Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742
any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-an-array

Answer (score 0):

```
q = q.replaceAll(")","");

String[] splittedString = q.split("(");
```

Now you have array of strings with elements like below.

ADD

EXP 1 4

SQR 1

Hope this is what you expected.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks and sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all elements in brackets separately, you can use a very simple (and easily readable) regex with the `split` method:

```
String[] array = s.split("[(*|)*|(*)*|)*(*]");
```

This will give you `{ADD, EXP 1 4, SQR 1, DIV 34 77, MULT 12 5 3 7, Sub 1 2}`.

If you want to keep nesting, that's more complicated and I'd strongly suggest you take a look at regex tutorials such as http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.